# Add Clipboard to the Running PSSession

Tags: powershell, exchange, clipboard

After some hours of scripting and searching for a solution for my problem i finally signed up to this forum.
Maybe someone could help me out with this.
I want to insert some ps-code to the ,from my exchange-server imported, pssession.
The code to insert into this session is included into a automatically generatet .txt file.
I allready found out how to exctract and copy the text within this file to my clipboard by using "Get-Content 'file-path'" --> Here's my issue: now I have to insert this text to the allready opened pssession and execute this, but i don't know how.

I allready tried to execute the txt-file as a ps1-file. The problem we got here is, that by executing this file another pssession gets startet(not the exchange-session).

Comment: I am glad you came to SU for help but your question is not written very well and is confusing.  Would you mind *formatting* it a bit and leaving out the part about signing up for the forum?  What I can glean from your question thus far is ***why*** are you trying to use the clipboard for this operation?  Please tell us ***exactly*** what you are trying to accomplish.  Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail its hard to interpret a correct answer for you but you could try something like:

```
$ps-code = Get-Clipboard 
$ps-code | Invoke-Expression
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-7.1

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.1